# IP Address Validation Using RegEx in Python Script MySQL Query

Tags: python, mysql

I am attempting to extract IP Address from a MySQL database using REGEX ina a SELECT statement. When i run the Query in the MySQL console it returns the expected results:

```
SELECT * FROM database.table WHERE field3 REGEXP '^(([0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])\\.){3}([0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])$';
```

When I run the same query through a python script it returns results that are not IP Addresses.

```
query = ("SELECT * FROM database.table WHERE field3 REGEXP '^(([0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])\\.){3}([0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])$';")
```

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: `\\.` probably. one of those backslashes will be parsed away by python, leaving only `\.` when it arrives at mysql, which then gets parsed as "this is a dot, not a single-char wildcard". `\\.` directly in mysql will be parsed as `backslash followed by dot`

Answer (score 0):

Marc B. nailed it. I'll quote his comment.

> \. probably. one of those backslashes will be parsed away by python, leaving only . when it arrives at mysql, which then gets parsed as "this is a dot, not a single-char wildcard". \. directly in mysql will be parsed as backslash followed by dot – Marc B

Answer (score 0):

Try putting an r before your string in python to make it a raw string, so that it correctly includes the back whacks.

e.g.

```
query = (r"SELECT * FROM database.table ...")
```